# Disable mat-checkbox inside mat-table based on data from server

Tags: angular6

In my application while adding New User I will select Group from dropdown and based on the selected Group, mat-table data will be loaded. It contains RoleName and a checkBox to select the Role. Group contains few roles and they will be checked based checkRole is true or false coming from server. I want to disable the check box when checkRole from server is true. The remaining CheckBoxes I should be able to check or uncheck. I tried multiple scenarios but while I check a checkbox it is also disabled.

```
<div class="mat-elevation-z8" style="border: 1px solid darkblue">
  <mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" id="matTable" matSort>
  <ng-container matColumnDef="roleName">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Role Name</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-label="Role Name">{{element.roleName}}</mat-cell>
  </ng-container>

   <!-- Action column -->
  <ng-container matColumnDef="checkRole">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef >Add Role to Group</mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" data-label="Add Role to Group">
        <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.checkRole" [disabled]="element.checkRole">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
     <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
     <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns" (click)="selectRow(row)"></mat-row>
</mat-table>
```